# Can We get a report for the values filled in radio button in DocuSign Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We have added two radio button with same group name and values as 'Y' & 'N'. Now, as a support team we need to track what all the users has choose in radio buttons for their respective document. For this we need to open and check values in all document.

Is there any way to get the report from docusign for the values filled in radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Manage tab you can only export form data (aka 'tab data') one a per envelope basis by selecting the envelope -> dropdown arrow on the right -> form data.

If this is a DocuSign Powerform scenario, you can download a CSV/XML file based off a date range, with all tab values for each envelope included in the download. Powerforms -> Select powerform -> dropdown arrow -> Form data.

I believe your only other alternative is a custom script using our API to generate such a report.