# PowerForms and its advantage

Tags: docusignapi

Few questions about PowerForms

What is the real advantage of using PowerForms? In which case(s) it is most useful?

In Docusign Classic View >> PowerForms, there is an option to download Form Data as XML and CSV. Can we download this data using APIs?
For this question, I referred this thread ["Can We get a report for the values filled in radio button in DocuSign Envelope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364873/can-we-get-a-report-for-the-values-filled-in-radio-button-in-docusign-envelope/33368473#33368473).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerForms are an easy way of referencing a DocuSign Template through the API without writing any code.  They are intended for less technical end-users who want to quickly access a Template through either `email` delivery or through a direct `link` (URL) but don't know / want to code it up.  Instead they manually initiate such requests through a created PowerForm.

With regards to the form data question- yes, you can programmatically retrieve the form data through the API.  You need to keep in mind that DocuSign `tabs` (aka  `fields`) are always with respect to recipients and not the document itself.

Therefore, you can make the [Get Tab Information For Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm) API call (REST version linked).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regarding tab information, I have used the **Get Tab Information For Recipient** API call  [link] (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Tab%20Information%20for%20a%20Recipient.htm). This works find when I have the envelopeId and the recipientId. How can I get envelopeId based on powerFormId? Is there any API for getting all the envelopeIds based on the powerFormId - as is seen in the downloaded Form Data csv file.

Comment: I think you mis-interpreted my answer, what I was trying to say is that EITHER you use PowerForms if you are a less-technical end user OR you use the DocuSign API.  I don't believe you can use the API to query information from a PowerForm.

Comment: Multiple websites are integrated with my web app. User might not directly visit my web app but come from different sources. My requirement is that I need to provide a link on another website which in integrated with my web application. So, when a user clicks the link [used powerforms] and completes the signing process on the website, the information should be available in my web app. In such cases, how can I get the information in my web app as is seen in Docusign form data csv. What parameters to consider?