# Can we retrieve PowerForm data through API?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any REST API call for retrieving  the PowerForm data as we get it from Docusign->PowerForms->Select PowerForm ->dropdown arrow ->Form Data as csv or xml format?

For this question,I referred this thread "[PowerForms and its advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736885/powerforms-and-its-advantage/33743170#33743170)".

Answer (score 2):

- There is no API call to mimic the bulk CSV/XML download that is offered for Powerforms in the web app.

Answer (score 2):

You can however, get the data through API by getting the envelope status: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/get-envelope-status
so you can mimic that behavior by doing some data transformation.

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.1 of the API I believe you can do this.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/powerforms/powerformdata/list/

Request
HTTP Request
GET
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/powerforms/{powerFormId}/form_data

Parameters
Path Parameters
accountId * string
The external account number (int) or account ID GUID.

powerFormId *   string
The ID of the PowerForm.

Query Parameters
data_layout string
The layout in which to return the PowerForm data. Valid values are:

Native
Csv_Classic
Csv_One_Envelope_Per_Line
Xml_Classic
from_date   string
The start date for a date range in UTC DateTime format.

Note: If this property is null, no date filtering is applied.

to_date string
The end date of a date range in UTC DateTime format. The default value is UtcNow.

- Required