# Getting the Powerforms List using Docusign Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

Do we have any Rest APIs to pull and push Power Forms? Exploring if we have an option to call PowerForms that are created in DocuSign and publish them (PowerForm) from our integration and recieve publish PF url back.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Powerforms must be managed within the DocuSign WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

See [Can we retrieve PowerForm data through API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174430/can-we-retrieve-powerform-data-through-api/76859480#76859480)
As of v2.1 of the API I believe you can do this. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/powerforms/powerformdata/list/

Request HTTP Request GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/powerforms/{powerFormId}/form_data

Parameters Path Parameters accountId * string
The external account number (int) or account ID GUID.

powerFormId * string
The ID of the PowerForm.

Query Parameters data_layout string
The layout in which to return the PowerForm data. Valid values are:

Native Csv_Classic Csv_One_Envelope_Per_Line Xml_Classic from_date string
The start date for a date range in UTC DateTime format.

Note: If this property is null, no date filtering is applied.

to_date string
The end date of a date range in UTC DateTime format. The default value is UtcNow.

Required